# How would I change my program so I turn this 2D array into a 3D one?

Tags: python, arrays, random

I am trying to code a quiz and at the moment it saves the students last score however I would like to change it so that it saves the last three. I've been made aware that I need to change the current 2d array I am using into a 3d one but I do not know how to do that.

```
class_number = prompt_int_big(
    "Before your score is saved, are you in class 1, 2 or 3? Press the matching number")

    filename = (str(class_number) + "txt")
    if any(name in s for s in filename):
        [name].insert(score), insert(level_of_difficulty)
    else:
        with open(filename, 'a') as f:
            f.write("\n" + str(name) + " scored " + str(score) +
                    " on difficulty level " + str(level_of_difficulty) + "\n")
        with open(filename) as f:
            lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
            lines.sort()
```

Comment: Please provide all the relevant parts of your code, so it is clear what each of your variables mean. for example, what is 'name' and what is 'score'? Where do you get them from? Also, please add examples of the files you are reading/writing.

Comment: This is the code of a quiz were the program asks a student what there name the level of difficulty they are working at and then gives them 10 arithmetic questions. They are then asked what class they are in and then their score is saved to the appropriate file.

Comment: Yeah, I got it the first time, but as long as you don't provide what I've asked for, I (and it seems like nobody else either) won't be able to help you. just edit your question so we can see the whole picture.

Comment: I cant give a picture of my whole code for a reason I can't say but I can provide you with a scrrenshot of the files that it writes

Comment: Here is the contents of one file name "2txt"

Comment: Bob scored 9 on difficulty level 2

NNNNN scored 9 on difficulty level 3

Steve scored 10 on difficulty level 2